# Can't connect Rails app to Postgres using PG gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg

I'm trying to connect a rails app to a remote Postgres database (using the PG gem) and getting issues.

I set my `database.yaml` file

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: testdb
  username: testuser
  password: "*******"
  host: **.***.***.***
  port: 5432
```

Then in my rails controller I have this line to connect to the db

```
conn = PG.connect( :dbname => 'testdb' )
```

And I get this error in response

```
"status": "error",
"message": "could not connect to server: No such file or directory\n\tIs the server running locally and accepting\n\tconnections on Unix domain socket \"/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432\"?\n"
```

I was under the impression that PG would pull from the database connection loaded in rails. If I do an inspect on the db configuration I see that it's pulling the `database.yaml` parameters

```
#<ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations::HashConfig:0x00007fd5ae0562d0 @env_name="development", @name="primary", @configuration_hash={:adapter=>"postgresql", :encoding=>"unicode", :database=>"testdb", :username=>"testuser", :password=>"*****", :host=>"**.***.***.***", :port=>5432}>
```

I'm able to successfully connect though if I pass in the necessary variables or connection string to PG instead

```
conn = PG::Connection.new( "postgresql://testuser:*******@**.***.***.***:5432/testdb" )
```

Comment: Why are you trying to open the connection in your controller manually?

Comment: It's just a test for now. I'll probably put the connection code somewhere else once I get it working.

Comment: You shouldn't need to connect manually. Set up your database configuration. Create your models and just try accessing the database through the model ... Or connect in with a `rails c` and just check your connection there. Don't try to create a new connection in your controller